# Swiper js sync slider in async method

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, swiper.js

In elementor page builder this is how I initialise swiper js

```
            var options = {
             // my swiper options 
            };
            const asyncSwiper = elementorFrontend.utils.swiper;
            new asyncSwiper('.tpslider', options).then((newSwiperInstance) => {
                var swiper = newSwiperInstance;
            });
            console.log(swiper); // returns undefined
```

How can I access `swiper` variable now ?

Comment: Did you get any solution with it? I'm also having the same issues.

Comment: I can see it through elementorFrontend.utils.swiper. But I am unable to get it to work even after copying an example found here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/swiper-is-not-defined-elementor-3-5/page

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
jQuery( window ).on( 'elementor/frontend/init', () => {
    var swiperElement = '#swiperContainer'
    var swiperConfig = {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        loop: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
    }

    //then use the code
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof Swiper ) {
        const asyncSwiper = elementorFrontend.utils.swiper;

        new asyncSwiper( swiperElement, swiperConfig ).then( ( newSwiperInstance ) => {
            console.log( 'New Swiper instance is ready: ', newSwiperInstance );

            mySwiper = newSwiperInstance;
        } );
    } else {
        console.log( 'Swiper global variable is ready, create a new instance: ', Swiper );

        mySwiper = new Swiper( swiperElement, swiperConfig );
    }
});
```

Make sure to follow how-to load your widgets as well.
https://developers.elementor.com/add-javascript-to-elementor-widgets/

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'swiper'). For me elementorFrontend.utils is undefined on elementor/frontend/init.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sync main slider to thumbs, you can do this:

```js
var sliderContainer = $scope.find('.main-slider');
var sliderSettings = {
    ...
};

var thumbsContainer = $scope.find('.thumbs-slider');
var thumbsSettings = {
    ...
};



if ( 'undefined' === typeof Swiper ) {
    const asyncSwiper = elementorFrontend.utils.swiper;

    new asyncSwiper( thumbsContainer, thumbsSettings ).then( ( newSwiperThumbsInstance ) => {
        var swiperThumbs = newSwiperThumbsInstance;
        sliderSettings["thumbs"] = { swiper: swiperThumbs  };

        new asyncSwiper( sliderContainer, sliderSettings ).then( ( newSwiperSliderInstance ) => {
            var swiperSlider = newSwiperSliderInstance;
        } );
    } );

}
else {

    var swiperThumbs = new Swiper(thumbsContainer, thumbsSettings);

    sliderSettings["thumbs"] = { swiper: swiperThumbs  };

    var swiper = new Swiper(sliderContainer, sliderSettings);

}
```